# I want to test if a list of URLs is valid

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, url

I have Googled for a solution to read through a bunch of URLs, in a text file, and test if each one is valid.  Anything, simple or complex, is fine.  Simpler is probably better.  Maybe getting a 200 response is the way to go.  As I said, I tested some scripts that I found online, and non worked.  Sometimes people want to see what has been tried already, but I don't think there is any sense in posting what does NOT work.

As a bonus, I'm wondering if there is a way to loop through all bookmarks in a browser, like Firefox specifically, and test if all URLs are valid or not.  I'm not sure that's doable, but it would be a nice-to-have!!

TIA everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests

with open('urls.txt', 'r') as file:
    urls = file.read().splitlines()

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    sc = r.status_code
    if sc == 200:
        valid = 'Valid'
    else:
        valid = "Not valid"
    print(f'URL: {url}')
    print(f'Status code: {sc}')
    print(f'{valid}')
```

urls.txt has one URL per line

You could also swap .read().splitlines() to .readlines() then loop with .strip().

**EDIT 1**

For a bad url, use try/except:

```
for url in urls:
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        sc = r.status_code
        if sc == 200:
            valid = 'Valid'
        else:
            valid = "Not valid"
        print(f'URL: {url}')
        print(f'Status code: {sc}')
        print(f'{valid}')
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f'URL: {url}')
        print('Error')
        print(e)
```

You can customise it for different exceptions; see here:

https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions

Comment: Thanks Jamesdeluk.  That works fine if all URLs are valid.  If one is not an actual URL, it shuts down and stops.  How can I get the code to continue all the way to the end, even if/when a bad URL is encountered?

Comment: The EDIT1 code works fine!  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a one-liner as follows:

```
[url for url in open('urls.txt').readlines() if requests.get(url.strip()).ok]
```

Note that it would probably be better to wrap things in a `try/except`, as a lot of requests done through `requests` will receive a `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError` rather than a status code if it cannot reach the host at all, is an invalid url, etc.